# Using IAnnotationTransformer outside testng.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

It is my understanding that IAnnotationTransformer classes run before the suite starts, hence it cannot be declared on a class level the same way as ITestListener, for example. So the usage of this I always see is adding it to the testng.xml file:

```
<suite name = "testSuite" >

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="TestAnnotationTransformer" />
    </listeners>

(...)
```

However, I am required to, some times, run the tests from the IDE: `right-click -> Run As -> TestNG Test`, so when doing this, the `testng-customsuite.xml` file is ran instead, which contains no listener declared.

I know that I can set a template xml file for TestNG through Eclipse, but since there are some people using IntelliJ in the team, I want to avoid doing that.

**My question is:** How can I make sure that my IAnnotationTransformer is always executed, no matter how I execute the tests or which IDE I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

TestNg's changes note indicates @Listeners is supported for IAnnotationTransformer if you are using 6.9.10 or higher.